# Convert dataset to excel byte array c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, dataset

I have dataset.
I want to export to excel file but without save on disk, but get only byte array.
I found solutions with save to disk only.
How I can ommit this step?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you can't. Just save it into the temp folder, and open it, remembering of course to clean it up again afterwards.

If you use COM automation you can create a new spreadsheet and set all the values yourself, but AFAIK that just creates a temp file anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the Excel file in xls file format using [EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com) library.

Check this code sample about [exporting dataset to Excel](http://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/export-dataset-to-excel.html).

Instead of saving on disk, use a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx).

```
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
xls.easy_WriteXLSFile_FromDataSet(memStream, dataset, 
                      new ExcelAutoFormat(Styles.AUTOFORMAT_EASYXLS1), "DataSet");
byte[] byteArray = memStream.ToArray();
```